# How to end the function in c# the file used by another process?

Tags: c#

I have a code and I want to close the function of the code here is the code :

```
Writer writetag = new Writer(@C:\Users\user1\Documents\mytext.txt);
writetag.Position = 0;
writetag.WriteString(textBox5.Text);
```

I want a after I save the text I want to use the file in another function

I try to add return; in the end of the code but it doesn't work

please help

because when i use the file in another function in the same program

it's give me error and it say :the file used by another program

i think because the file used by the save function.

thank

Comment: Since Magnus' answer was correct you should mark it as correct, so others will easily know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to close the writer with either the [`using(){}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block (which automatically Disposes the the object on exit) or manually call the close method of the writer like this [`writer.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before your function exits

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the `Writer`.

```
using(Writer writetag = new Writer(@C:\Users\user1\Documents\mytext.txt))
{
   writetag.Position = 0;
   writetag.WriteString(textBox5.Text);
}
```

Comment: thank you man you have help me a lot thank and thank for fast response

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that `Writer` is actually `StreamWriter`.

With that assumption, you must `Close()` the `StreamWriter` before another process has access to the file.  Even better, you could use a `using` statment to ensure that your file will always be closed once it loses scope.

```
using(var writeTag = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\mytext.txt"))
{
  // writeTag.BaseStream.Position = 0; // Not needed and does nothing...
  writeTag.Write(textBox5.Text);
}
```